# Python read csv with array columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some csv files including array columns. For example:

```
a,b,c
1,1|2|3,4.5|5.5|6.5
2,7|8|9,10.5|11.5|12.5
```

Delimter 1 is `,` to sepperate fields a, b and c. Delimiter 2 is `|` in this case, but could be changed.

Is there a possibility in python to read this as a pandas dataframe directly? Field b and c should be an array/series inside the dataframe.

What I do now is reading the csv as strings:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype='str')
```

Then use `np.fromstring` to convert all strings to numpy arrays:

```
type_dict = {
  "a": "int",
  "b": "int",
  "c": "float"
}

def make_split(text, dt):
    return np.fromstring(text, sep="|", dtype=dt)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(make_split, dt=type_dict[x.name]))
```

But this takes several minutes for my files. Is there a faster option?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `converters` parameter of `.read_csv()` to parse columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={
    'b': lambda x: np.array(x.split('|'), dtype='int'),
    'c': lambda x: np.array(x.split('|'), dtype='float')
    })
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a          b                   c
0  1  [1, 2, 3]     [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]
1  2  [7, 8, 9]  [10.5, 11.5, 12.5]
```

Comment: You might want to define a named function and use that in the dictionary

Comment: This is slightly faster than my version, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'csv2.txt', sep=',')


df['b']=df['b'].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])
df['c']=df['c'].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
df
```

```
a   b   c
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]
1   2   [7, 8, 9]   [10.5, 11.5, 12.5]
```

Comment: This way I still get strings which aren't numpy lists. The conversion to the correct types takes the most time.

Comment: I updated it to use a numpy array and work for a generic dataframe:

```df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split("|").apply(lambda y: np.array(y, dtype=type_dict[x.name])))```

This is the fastest solution at the moment.